# Dynamic Creation of a div with Javascript with css styling seems to not work even with a correct code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the code below that lists down the contents of a variable . Since the contents are simply text, I'd like to put some style on them by encapsulating their divs using css in editing the . The code works fine except when I include the snippet for the css.

```
newrow.style.cssText = 'width:200px;height:200px;-moz-border-radius:100px;border:1px  solid #ddd;-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px  #fff;display:none;';
```

Here's the for-loop

```
for (a = 0; a < output.length; a++)
    {
    var newrow = document.createElement("div");

    newrow.style.cssText = 'width:200px;height:200px;-moz-border-radius:100px;border:1px  solid #ddd;-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px  #fff;display:none;';
    var tableRow = resulttable.appendChild(newrow);
    var cell = tableRow.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(output[a] + " "));
        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(output.holder[a]));
    }
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Seems to work for me on Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/XV9Ew/

Comment: Wild guess: Wrap the css text in double quotes ("), maybe the semi-colons in the string are causing a problem.

Comment: `-moz-` is deprecated for `box-shadow` and `border-radius` (since a long time) Anyway, are you really adding a div as child to a table, and then adding table cells to that div? I wouldn't expect that to work with or without the css. But at least the `display:none` ensures no one will have to see the result, so there's that.

Comment: Thanks eevaa! Your solution worked wonders! :D